How to SQL count same data of multi column
enter image description here



op0
op1
op2
op3
op4
op5




2309
2799
9738





233001
233861
236731
9999




2309
233001
8931





233001
236731






2309
233001
2792
2799
9999



232
233001






2309
233001
2799





233001
233861
236731
9999





I need to count
enter image description here



all op
count




2309
4


232
1


233001
7


233861
2


236731
3


2792
1


2799
3


8931
1


9738
1


9999
3



I need a SQL query to select multi column

please format your question. clean code, no pictures

In order to achieve your desired result you can do something like:
SELECT Value AS op, COUNT(*) AS count
FROM (
    SELECT op0 AS Value FROM table1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT op1 FROM table1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT op2 FROM table1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT op3 FROM table1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT op4 FROM table1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT op5 FROM table1
) AS AllOps
WHERE Value IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY Value
ORDER BY count DESC;

Explanation:
To count the occurrences of each unique value, you can:

Use UNION ALL to combine all the columns into a single column named Value. The UNION ALL is used instead of UNION to keep all duplicate values for accurate counting.
Select non-null values from the UNION ALL subquery, group them by the Value, and count the occurrences using COUNT(*). The results are ordered by the count in descending order.


If i want to sum all count in sql?
SELECT Value AS op, COUNT(*) AS count
FROM (
SELECT op0 AS Value FROM table1
UNION ALL
SELECT op1 FROM table1
UNION ALL
SELECT op2 FROM table1
UNION ALL
SELECT op3 FROM table1
UNION ALL
SELECT op4 FROM table1
UNION ALL
SELECT op5 FROM table1
) AS AllOps
WHERE Value IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY Value
ORDER BY count DESC;
How to

For that you will have to create a separate question, i can still give you a hint your entire query will turn into a subquery for fetching sum

i did not quite get your comment
